# Send data to google chart function

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have 3 google charts which are identical apart from the data and id of the chart.
At the moment I call these charts like this.

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic2);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic3);
```

Because the charts are almost identical I would like one function instead of 3, as I like to use less code if possible, but when I do this it doesn't work.
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic(mydata,myid));

If I could send the data like this, then I wouldn't need 3 functions, I would only need one drawBasic function, with different data every time it is called.
I won't paste all 3 functions I will just paste the one function to show how my function is laid out.

```
function drawBasic() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

    data.addRows([
        [new Date(2016, 4), 0],[new Date(2016, 5), 0],[new Date(2016, 6), 0],[new Date(2016, 7), 0],[new Date(2016, 8), 0],[new Date(2016, 9), 0]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Total Sales Last Six Months',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Sales'
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Month'
        },
            backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            'animation':{duration:1000,easing:'out'}
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('total_sales_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);

    setTimeout(function(){
        data.setValue(0,1,14690);
        data.setValue(1,1,2785);
        data.setValue(2,1,23345);
        data.setValue(3,1,10345);
        data.setValue(4,1,12456);
        data.setValue(5,1,19642);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    },1000);    
}
```

So is it possible for me to send my data to the function. I am new to google charts, but where possible I don't like using 3 functions when I can get away with only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setOnLoadCallback` is meant to be used *once* per page load

however, you can add the `callback` to the `load` statement

then call the draw function from there...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawBasic(mydata1, myid1);
    drawBasic(mydata2, myid2);

    function drawBasic(data, id) {
      ...
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: Well I did come up with a solution that worked, but your solution was better. My solution was this var myData = [[new Date(2016, 4),50],[new Date(2016, 5),78],[new Date(2016, 6),99],[new Date(2016, 7),50],[new Date(2016, 8),78],[new Date(2016, 9),99]];
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawBasic('total_hr_chart',myData);
}); but this mean't I had to call setOnLoadCallback 3 times. Your solution was so much better, and now I am using your solution. I have managed to reduce my code by about 60 lines. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do sth like:

```
var data=[[1,2],[3,4]];
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
drawBasic(data[i]);
}
});
```

This small function calls drawBasic with one array element as arguments list.
So your drawBasic function will be called like this:

```
drawBasic([1,2]);
drawBasic([3,4]);
```

Comment: Just tried this code and it is giving me an error. Trying to work it out now. It is giving me the error on the google.charts line. However it doesn't tell me what the error is, unfortunately

Comment: I am getting the error in Dreamweaver, and not a browser??